# How to have two arguments change the value of one argument in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to have two arguments in `argparse` change the value of one argument using the `dest` parameter in one of the `add_agrument` calls.

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', default='file.in')
parser.add_argument('--no-input', dest='input', action='store_false')
```

The intended behavior of the program is `input` will have the value of `file.in` by default, or whatever is passed with the `-i` argument. This part works fine, but I also want `input` to have the value `False` if the `--no-input` flag is used. This is the part I'm having trouble with.

If I switch around the statements `input` gets the value `True` if the `--no-input` flag is not passed, which seems to mean only one argument will be considered. Is there any way to change this?

P.S. I *could* change the structure of the program to work around this, but I'm curious if it's possible at all.

Comment: the first one defined sets 'input' to its default (which is True for store_false).  Show `args` for various inputs.  The word description isn't clear enough.

Comment: Good call. With a lot more testing, I believe this might be a problem with the arguments might be the issue, with how `sys.argv` deals with bash variables. In a much simpler program, my code actually works the way I want it to.